# As tags deveriam ser escritas em português?

Tags: debate, tags

Ao ver a tag [checksum](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checksum), indaguei-me se as tags deveriam ser escritas em português. No contexto da programação, sabemos que existem muitos termos que muitos nem traduzem no seu dia-a-dia, como o  *checksum*, *database*, *upload*, *download*, entre outros.

A tag [checksum](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checksum) deveria ser traduzida para [soma-de-verificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soma-de-verifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o), por exemplo?

Comment: Não percebi o motivo dos -1.

Comment: @JorgeB. Também não entendi. Peço aos _downvoters_ que sugiram soluções para que eu possa melhorar minha questão.

Comment: @JorgeB no meta, os votos negativos significam "eu não concordo com a ideia proposta". Vide http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites

Comment: @Renan ele não deu nenhuma ideia, ele fez apenas uma pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB para uma pergunta como "as tags deveriam ser escritas em português?", cada voto negativo deve ser interpretado como um usuário dizendo "não, não deveriam". Como o link que eu passei antes diz, nos metas os votos não são medidores de qualidade, mas sim de concordância.

Comment: @Renan eu sei, disso, mas costuma ser quando há uma sugestão do autor, que não é o caso, ele só pergunta se deveriam. Eu não acho que neste caso se deva dar -1. Afinal é só uma pergunta e não uma sugestão.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Me parece que não, acho que as pessoas teriam que parar para pensar para entender  oque seria Soma de Verificação, as pessoas entendem fácil o que é *checksum*.

Também me parece que *Notification* é o nome da tecnologia, portanto próprio e não cabe tradução.

Para uma *tag* ser preferida em português tem que haver uma palavra ou expressão em português que as pessoas reconhecem normalmente. Se o reconhecimento dentro da nossa área é maior pelo termo em inglês ele é preferido. As *tags* devem dar o melhor entendimento possível.

Comment: Me atento a sua afirmação, a qual parece responder perfeitamente a pergunta: **"As tags devem dar o melhor entendimento possível."**