# Tags [lado-do-cliente] e [lado-do-servidor] deveriam ser sinônimos de [client-side] e [server-side] respectitivamente?

Tags: debate, tags, tags-sinônimas

No site existem duas tags:

- [lado-do-cliente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lado-do-cliente) com o sinônimo [client-side](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-side)
- [lado-do-servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lado-do-servidor) com o sinônimo [server-side](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side)

Para mim as **tags em inglês deveriam ser as principais**, porque nesse caso o entendimento é maior que a tradução em português. Sei que são sinônimas já, mas acho que em inglês deixaria mais fácil o propósito dessas tags.

Seria como traduzir [checksum](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checksum) para [soma-de-verificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soma-de-verifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Checksum é mais contextual e mais comum e acredito que seja por isso que tenhamos a versão em inglês (nesse caso como principal e única tag).

> @Maniero: As tags *devem* dar o maior entendimento possível.
>   ["As tags deveriam ser escritas em português?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5331/as-tags-deveriam-ser-escritas-em-portugu%C3%AAs)

Bem, isso é só minha opinião, quero saber de vocês.

Comment: Eu concordo contigo neste "caso especifico" +1, ainda sim creio que para outras tags isso pode variar, por isso fiquei em duvida se as pessoas leram e/ou entenderam a sua pergunta, penso que a pergunta soa como qualquer tag que exista em inglês de um termo comum ligado aos tópicos do SOpt.

Answer (score 4):

Discordo que este caso seja tão óbvio assim. Me parece que o português é perfeitamente compreensível, e poderia ser o preferido por causa disto. Por outro lado o termo em inglês é mais usado.

Sou favorável usar termos em português sempre que couberem, sem exageros. Não vamos falar em rato, linha de encadeamento de execução e principalmente de rede do éter (ok, essa foi brincadeira).

Quis colocar esta posição, mas deixar o debate rolar. Por mim fica o português, mas não fecho questão.

Comment: Não vamos falar em rato porquê? Nos aqui chamamos "mouse" de rato mesmo. ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. foi justamente por isso que eu falei :P